# Profile not creating when creating a User with Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF for my project and I need help in automatically creating a Profile instance for a User model when a User is created. My signals is:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with the code below:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, user_type='')

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```